# Warning: Illegal offset type in

Tags: php, html, css

As I am trying to get firstname and lastname from clientdb . But when i try to get the firstname and lastname from the query it shows error like.My code is below

> Warning: Illegal offset type in

```
<?php
include_once('../php/session.php');
$client = "SELECT fname,lname FROM clientdb WHERE clientemail='$usercheck'";
$resultclient = mysqli_query($con,$client) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bus Ticket Resevation - Userpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/client-page.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="customer-login.php" method="post" class="customer-login">
   <fieldset class=".one">
       <legend>User-Details:</legend>
       <table class="usertable">
           <tr>
               <td><label>Username or Email:</label></td>
               <td><?php echo "$_POST[$resultclient]";?></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not [fetching](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) any data from your query, only executing, so do it

```
$resultclient = mysqli_query($con,$client) or die(mysqli_error());
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($resultclient);
```

Then you can use your data by calling `$result` and put in global scope your column name

```
<td><label>Username or Email:</label></td>
<td><?php echo $result['fname'];?></td>
```

You can also use both column calling their name in global scope

Answer (score 2):

You have to fetch the result as array or object.Here I have fetched using array.

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultclient);

//just check whether your getting details from database
print_r($row);

//it returns as associative array u can reference the database column name as a key in the array like...
echo "<br>";
echo $row['fname']; 
echo "<br>";
echo $row['lname'];
echo "<br>";

// or another way
echo $row[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $row[1];
echo "<br>";
```